# cannot getChildByName starling stage

Tags: actionscript-3, object, stage

I am trying to get a reference to an object that is placed on starling stage named "_shooterHero" from an external class which is "bullet".

I have tried using getChildByName with:

`starling.core.stage` and `starling.current.nativeStage`, but without any luck

The code right now:

```
var hero= Starling.current.stage.getChildByName("_shooterHero");
trace (hero.name)
```

Comment: why are you trying to get it from stage and not get a reference to it from the class where it is defined?

Comment: also I see you named it "_hero" but you try to get child with name "_shooterHero", i do not see the point in here! is this a type you made in current post or this is your real code?

Comment: Adrian Pirvulescu, yes it was a typing error I made

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve your problem:

1. Make hero publicly accessible. When you create a new hero (wherever that is) you can also add public getter/setter methods to allow your external class to access it.
2. Create a "model" class that can be referenced by the singleton getInstance() pattern. Then proceed as in (1).
3. Are you sure the sprite has been added to the stage? You can check this by doing Starling.current.stage.getChildByName(hero); although for this would need to have access to the hero variable.